# Why does casting geometry to box2d give different precision from 2 databases

Tags: postgis, postgresql, sql, precision, migration

I have a postgresql 9.0 DB with postgis extension that I have migrated to another server running postgresql 11.13. Visual inspection of the tables shows matching data in raw form. E.g.:

When retrieving a coverage geometry as a hexadecimal I see the same value from both systems:

`SELECT coverage from "World" FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY;`

`01060000000100000001030000000100000005000000BC5CC477622750C0E54691B586F212C0BC5CC477622750C000000000000000000000000000004EC000000000000000000000000000004EC0E54691B586F212C0BC5CC477622750C0E54691B586F212C0`

But when I cast that value to a box2d I am losing decimal precision in the postgresql 11.13 db. E.g.:

`SELECT CAST(coverage AS box2d) from "World" FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY;`

- from postgresql 9.0 DB => `BOX(-64.6153869628906 -4.73684215545654,-60 0)`
- from postgresql 11.13 D => `BOX(-64.615385 -4.736842,-60 0)`

How come? And how can I maintain the same decimal precision?

Comment: The geometry you have provided has vertices with only 6 decimals. Either geometries are different in both DBs, which would point to an issue in the way you have exported/imported the geometries, or your old box2D is erroneous.

Comment: @JGH you have put your finger on it, thanks, I had a look at the geometry functions, their link symbol is different
BOX2DFLOAT4_LWGEOM vs
BOX2D_LWGEOM

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@JGH pointed out that the geometry cast function or BOX2D type must have changed. This is true.

The issue is that postgresql 9.0 uses postgis 1.5 extension. Where as the postgresql 11.13 uses postgis 2.5.1 that includes changes made to improve floating point precision and accuracy.

In post gis 2.0 release notes (https://postgis.net/docs/PostGIS_Special_Functions_Index.html#NewFunctions_2_0_Changed) they mention the following:

> Bounding boxes of geometries have been changed from float4 to double
> precision (float8). This has an impact on answers you get using
> bounding box operators and casting of bounding boxes to geometries.
> E.g ST_SetSRID(abbox) will often return a different more accurate
> answer in PostGIS 2.0+ than it did in prior versions which may very
> well slightly change answers to view port queries.